# Grails 2.4.4 plugin BootStrap order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, plugins

It does not seem possible to control the order which plugins bootstraps are executed.  We need our plugins bootstraps to run after a core services bootstrap.

We have tried:

```
   def loadAfter = ['CoreservicesGrailsPlugin']
```

in the SomeDependentGrailsPlugin.groovy file, but this has no effect.  we also tried putting:

```
  def loadBefore = ['SomeDependentGrailsPlugin']
```

In our CoreservicesGrailsPlugin.groovy class.

Note, because we are actively developing the plugins, they are bot packaged completed plugins, so we have them defined thusly in our grails apps BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.location.coreservices = "../coreservices"
grails.plugin.location.someDependentPlugin= "../someDependentPluginDir"
```

Note: changing the order of these has no effect on the boostrap order.

We also tried:

```
def dependsOn = [CoreservicesGrailsPlugin: "*"]
```

Which does indeed fix the boostrap order, but then fails to run with this error:

```
   ! CoreservicesGrailsPlugin (Required: *, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]
```

Also tried:

```
    def dependsOn = [coreservices: "*"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Grails are you using? You may want to include that in your question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried using `coreservicesGrailsPlugin` or `coreservicesgrailsplugin` for the name when defining `loadAfter` or `loadBefore`? The reason why I ask is because all the plugin names appear to be lowercase or at least bean named in the docs: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/plugins.html

Comment: tried every combination of case, no luck unfortunately.